# Is it a good use case for eval in Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, eval

I am developing a Chrome extension that absolutely always needs to run with the newest code.

Now, this is a problem that I am not quite sure how to solve while not going for `eval()` alike functionality.

I designed it to fetch the newest script from server over HTTPS, then execute it using `new Function()`

It's absolutely most important to have extension run using newest code for every user and updates managed by Google don't solve that problem cause they are usually delayed or require user to update it manually.

CSP only allows for scripts executed from domain specified by me, but I am also using `unsafe-eval` although I can encode these scripts using hash for more security.

Scripts require access to page DOM and `chrome.*` API. I can't just specify them as `script src` in popup, because that's not the point.

Are there better solutions to this problem?

Comment: Is it an option to run the extensions in Developer mode? You could update the extension when you find a new script avail.  Just use a version. Without running in dev mode, the script will not be able to change itself, in addition, you will need to refresh the page after the script updates.

Comment: This will result in your extension being rejected from the store, so no.

Comment: @Ry︁ I actually have two extensions working this way in the store and no problems so far.